# Cancelling extrude still leaves extra geometry

Tags: modeling, interface

Steps:

- Create a cube

[image]

- Start extruding the top face, but either right-click or press Esc to cancel

[image]

As you can see, the number of objects (verts / edges / faces / tris) increased, even though the action was cancelled.

- Undoing the action (that was supposedly cancelled) reverts to previous count

Am I missing something here about the intended functionality of <kbd>Esc</kbd> / right click when doing extrude (and other actions)e or is this a feature / bug?

Comment: Check out [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J53_mcZCnj8) at 8:20 to see this behaviour used as a feature. Thanks to [gandalf3](http://blender.stackexchange.com/users/599/gandalf3) for explaining what's happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>E</kbd> is really calling [`extrude_region_move()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_5/bpy.ops.mesh.html?#bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move), which is a two part operation. It extrudes the selection *and then moves it as if you had pressed* <kbd>G</kbd>.
Pressing RMB or <kbd>Esc</kbd> will cancel the move part of the operation, but not the extrusion.

This is actually useful behavior, as it allows you to easily keep the extruded geometry (or loop cut) in place (maybe you want to scale it or something). If you don't want the extruded geometry, you can of course undo it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

This goes for all two part operations, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> *loop cut **and slide*** ([`loopcut_slide`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_5/bpy.ops.mesh.html?#bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide)).

Note that there are actually one part equivalents for these, but there aren't shortcuts for them (to my knowledge).
If you press <kbd>Space</kbd> in edit mode and search for e.g. *Loop cut*:

[image]

Pressing *Loop Cut* will put you in modal operator for cutting loops, just like pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, but it won't slide them like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> does once the cuts are confirmed (and if they are not confirmed, e.g. by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> there will be no cuts made at all).

Comment: Great answer! I like that you included the operation names.