# Cancelled extrusion of a face, now its a different color?

Tags: faces, extrude

[image: mesh showing the problem face]

I extruded a face then cancelled it (its the darker face). Now its behaving differently, and I can see a color change too. How do I remove it?

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10655/cancelling-extrude-still-leaves-extra-geometry.  You didn't cancel extrusion, you cancelled only movement of the exturded face which results in 2 faces stacked on top of each other.To take screenshots instead of photos press Ctrl+F3 when inside of  Blender

Comment: Please use screenshots, next time, not photos of your display, these are barely visible

Comment: I'll keep that in mind...

Answer (score 2):

You now have two faces occupying the same space. If you haven't done anything else you can step backwards by pressing Alt + "Z". Otherwise, in Edit Mode select one of the faces and delete it by pressing "X" and choosing "Only Faces" from the drop down.

Comment: I pressed  ctrl +z like million times... but it worked... thanks anyways..

Comment: I tried remove doubles but it didn't work... Ctrl +z works but I want to know what happened there

Comment: Please re-read my answer. When you Extruded you created an additional Face. You need to "Undo" which you ultimately did by pressing CTRL + "Z". Alternatively  you could have deleted the extra face you created when you attempted to extrude.

Comment: I tried removing that face but it didn't work.... someone said something about flip faces I think that might have worked. What do you think?

Comment: If it was a flipped Normal the face would be darker than the others.

Comment: For your future reference you can see which way the normals are pointing in “Edit Mode” in the “Mesh Display” portion of the Transform Properties panel (Toggled in/out with the “N” key) there is a section labeled “Normals”. If you click on the third cube icon blue lines will appear on your mesh indicating the direction the normals of your Faces are pointing.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

As previously mentioned by others, this is caused by double vertices/faces, which is recognizable by the weird pixelated "shadows" appearing on the face.

This is easily removed by selecting all your vertices by pressing A, go to mesh tools and click "Remove Doubles":
[image]
The button on the bottom.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't really think gifs are required here, this process is well-documented already. Note that flipping normals direction is not enough in this case because the reason of the normals misbehaviour is double vertices which are better to remove.

Comment: Ah, noticed the double verts now by the weird shading. The image quality isn't much to brag about so I missed it and mistook it for a flipped face at first glance.

Comment: Freemox 7.... I think the flip face should work... I tried remove doubles but it didn't work... How to repeat that mistake so that I can check it ..

Comment: It's still not resolve for you? You could go to edit mode, press Z to view vireframe, press B for box selection and select the faulty face(s). Make sure you deselect the face(s) on the other side of your mesh, and press X to delete. This will remove ALL faces currently selected. Then simply select the four verts surrounding the face you deleted, and press F til fill it with a new face